# VS Code: How to set that when I press CTRL + UP or DOWN arrow, the cursor move with the page?

Tags: visual-studio-code

My problem is that when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> or <kbd>down</kbd> arrow, the cursor doesn't move when it reaches the border of the page, and therefore when I release the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> button, the page "bumps" to where the cursor is.

Is it possible to change this behaviour?

For example in Visual Studio IDE, the cursor is "anchored" to the top of the page if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>down</kbd> arrow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a workaround.

Edit your *keybinding.json* and add this:

```json
{
    "key": "ctrl+up",
    "command": "editorScroll",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": 
    {
        "to": "up",
        "by": "line",
        "revealCursor": true
    }
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+down",
    "command": "editorScroll",
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "args": 
    {
        "to": "down",
        "by": "line",
        "revealCursor": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! It did work like a charm! Only one question... to do it I had to manually go to my settings dir and search the file... Is there a way to edit the file within vscode like you do for user settings?

Comment: @Luca: If you go to the `Keyboard Shortcuts` in the top right is an icon to edit the `json` file.

Comment: Is there a similar workaround possible for VS Community 19? I want the opposite to what OP wants - to have the default VS Code behavior in my VS Community

Comment: Hi @AshF. Do you know if this answer is still valid?  I've added this snippet to keybindins.json, but my cursor still does not move with ctrl+up/down.  I'm running VSCode v1.60.0.

Comment: @cag8f Yes, it's still valid.  I've just tried removing those lines from my keybindings.json and the cursor now goes offscreen.  Make sure that you add them at the end of the .json incase something else is overriding them.

Comment: Does not work 100% for me. I'm using these settings, but the cursor moves *only if* the page scrolling would hide it otherwise. EG if the cursor is at the center of the page, you scroll up 5 lines, the page scrolls but the cursor doesn't. If the cursor was at the bottom of the page, then it'd scroll up together with the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep the cursor where it was on the screen, you can do the followings:

1. First install the [multi-command](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryuta46.multi-command) extension to VSCode.
2. Open your the settings JSON and paste these commands into it:

   ```
    "multiCommand.commands": [
    {
        "command": "multiCommand.keepCursorPosScrollUp",
        "sequence": [
            {
                "command": "editorScroll",
                "args":{
                    "to": "up",
                    "by": "line",
                    "revealCursor": false
                }
            },
            "cursorUp"
        ]
    },
    {
        "command": "multiCommand.keepCursorPosScrollDown",
        "sequence": [
            {
                "command": "editorScroll",
                "args":{
                    "to": "down",
                    "by": "line",
                    "revealCursor": false
                }
            },
            "cursorDown"
        ]
    }
   ```

   ]
3. Open your keyboard shortcuts JSON and paste the followings into it:

   ```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+up",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "command": "multiCommand.keepCursorPosScrollUp"
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+down",
        "command": "extension.multiCommand.execute",
        "args": {
            "command": "multiCommand.keepCursorPosScrollDown"
        },
        "when": "editorTextFocus"
    }
   ```

Save the files, you're done. :)