# VS Code - keyboard shortcut to Move Cursor to the center of current screen After Keyboard Scrolling

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

After you scroll in the Editor using the keyboard (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>UpArrow</kbd>/<kbd>DownArrow</kbd>), the cursor stays behind where it was, maybe 5-10 screens back.

Is there a command to move the cursor into the center of the current screen that I am viewing, so that I can edit whatever I am looking at?

I could do "Go To Line" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, then type the line number), but I am looking for a single-press keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this in your keybindings.json:

```
{
  "key": "alt+m",           // or whatever binding you choose
  "command": "cursorMove",
  "args": {
      "to": "viewPortCenter"
  }
}
```

See also: [to automatically move cursor as you scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997089/vscode-how-to-set-that-when-i-press-ctrl-up-or-down-arrow-the-cursor-move-wi) if that is desirable.

Comment: I've set it to Ctrl+Shift+Insert, by the way - close to Ctrl+Up/Down.