# Visual Studio Community 2019 Text Editor Ctrl Up/Down behavior - keyboard vertical scrolling while preserving cursor position always

Tags: c#, visual-studio, scroll, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to keep my cursor position while vertical scrolling in all situations. <kbd>Ctrl+Up/Dn</kbd> shortcuts preserve while current selected/highlighted line is within Text Editor view. Once it moves out, the cursor jumps to first (<kbd>Dn</kbd>) or last (<kbd>Up</kbd>) position in Text Editor.

Use example: Writing code - peeking up/down the text editor with keyboard - continuing to write code at the same location/line.

The current VS Code default behavior for <kbd>Ctrl+Up/Dn</kbd> does this, while offering shortcut customization to get VS Community behavior. Is there a command or keybinding.json alternative I can use for VIsual Studio Community to achieve this behavior?

I searched multiple settings, enabled General - Settings - Enable virtual space, searched Environment -> Keyboard -> Show commands containing "Scroll" or "EmacsScroll" etc, but haven't been successful. I don't think a macro could solve this satisfactorily.

**EDIT**: Corrected wrongly termed "horizontal" scrolling to "vertical"

Comment: The same(similar) command in Visual Studio is also `ScrollLineUp` or `ScrollLineDown`(using `Ctrl + Up Arrow` or `Ctrl + Down Arrow`), but they are not work as the same as in Visual Studio Code. You can suggest this feature(improvement) to Visual Studio Product Team in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=8&entry=suggestion&q=MultiBinding).

Comment: @KyleWang VS Code offers a workaround - you can edit its keybindings.json file. I mentioned it already in my question, it is well explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997089/vscode-how-to-set-that-when-i-press-ctrl-up-or-down-arrow-the-cursor-move-wi#50003375. Is there a similar solution in VS Community?

Comment: I’m afraid, as far as I know, there isn’t a similar feature in Visual Studio. In Visual Studio you can set this option “apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme” to “Visual Studio Code” from Tools > Options > Environment > Keyboard, but it seems apply the default `keybindings.json` file of VS Code, you can try to change the default `keybindings.json` file if it is possible and see if it works.