# Removed the key bindinds for Ctrl+UpArrow from my keybindings. But the Ctrl+Up keystroke combination still moves my lines up

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to remove the keybinding of Ctrl+UpArrow to copy the line one line above which is really annoying. I have tried a bunch of suggestions from StackOverflow but the key bindings dont seem to change.

I am using shortcut Ctrl+K Ctrl-S to open the keyboard binding settings. Right now i have deleted all the bindings corresponding to Ctrl+ Up arrow, but the line is still copying up.

I ideally want my Ctrl + UpArrow to take me one page up with cursor there.

On top of that my command palette seems top be not working with ctrl+shift + p. When i search command palette in vscode keyboard bindings, there is no option.

[Visual Studio Code keybindings - Running two or more commands with one shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611435/visual-studio-code-keybindings-running-two-or-more-commands-with-one-shortcut)

[VS Code: How to set that when I press CTRL + UP or DOWN arrow, the cursor move with the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49997089/vs-code-how-to-set-that-when-i-press-ctrl-up-or-down-arrow-the-cursor-move-w)

THESE HAD LITERALLY NO EFFECT

Comment: command palette command ID is `workbench.action.showCommands`. Please show us the contents of your keybindings.json (Use the `Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` command in the command palette to open that file)

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.